# Write to temp file and read from command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-writing, temp, file-read

I need to write a temporary file to a n*x machine using python3 so that I can read it from the command line.

```
import tempfile
import subprocess
from os import path

string = 'hi *there*'

# run markdown server-side
tfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+', suffix='.txt', prefix='prove-math-')
tfile.write(string)
fpath = tfile.name
markdown_path = path.join(LIB_DIR, 'Markdown.pl')
command = [markdown_path, fpath]
completed_process = subprocess.run(command, check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
string = completed_process.stdout.decode()
tfile.close()

print(string)
```

The output should be `'<p>hi <em>there</em></p>'`, but the actual output is `'\n'`, which suggests to me that `Markdown.pl` read the contents of the file as `'\n'`.

Comment: path.join ? Where's path?

Comment: @UbdusSamad EDIT: `from os import path` is in the code but I had forgotten to include it here.  Now fixed.

Comment: Did you try tfile.flush() ??

Comment: I don't know much about the tempfile module, but doesn't it needs to be flush or properly closed to write the data like a normal file?

Comment: File Handel from `tempfile` follow the same Rules as File Handle from `open(...`.

Comment: @UbdusSamad `tfile.flush()` seems to do the trick!

Comment: Ishall put it in the answer then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use,

> file_obj.flush()

In your case, you'll have to use

```
tfile.flush()
```

It'll write to the file on being called upon!

Comment: Read the comments, I suggested him to close it as well, but, whatever works for him is the answer my friend!

Comment: @SergeBallesta I believe that `tfile.close()` doesn't work because `tempfile` deletes the file after closing it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Also, this is only helpful information if you list which operating systems will give an issue.  The [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tempfile.html?highlight=tempfile#module-tempfile) docs only mention that an issue will occur with Windows NT or later.